# Theme Icons not Loading in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I have installed PhpMyAdmin on a Raspberry Pi 4 4 GB running full Raspbian. Nginx is my web server. An application is running on the web server and can access the database. PhpMyAdmin loads in the browser and I can log in and use it but no icons load. I see small image symbols to the left of the text the icons would match with. For examples the ship logo does not display at the top of the login page and no database tree displays in the left navigation bar, just text on top of text. I have tried giving maximum permissions (777) but there was no change. All the apps were installed separately -- not part of a LAMP package.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out partially helped by an answer on this site. In my site conf file for nginx I added this INSIDE a location block I had added for phpmyadmin:

```
location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
            root /usr/share/;
```

After that the PhpMyAdmin icons displayed.